# ReplaceWhere greater than year partition in delta table

Tags: pyspark, databricks

This is how my data is stored in 'year' partition in a delta table
[image]

This is the query I want to write. df_data_model only has data for years 2020 and above. After executing this query I only want year greater than 2020 to be present in delta table and rest deleted. Can this be achived with a query like this ? If yes what should I write in `<?>` . If not what additional script do I need to write if I am to automate this.

The **gist** of the question is "Delete data that do not exist in DF, replace data that exists and create new folders for new data"

```
(df_data_model
 .write
 .partitionBy("Year")
 .mode('overwrite') 
 .option("replaceWhere", "<?>")
 .format('delta')
 .save(path_delta)
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

The `replaceWhere` works and there wont be no data in the folders. But the folders remain there for 7 days and it will be automatically deleted.

If you load from the delta table and check the years it will only have 2020 and 2021. But folders will remain for 2017-2019 for 7 days.